# Don't (verb)... (like) OR (unlike) I did

Tags: word-usage, verbs, expressions

Say my intention is to say "I did this bad things to her, but you shouldn't do it":

> - Don't do that mean thing to her **like** how I did.
> - Don't do that mean thing to her **unlike** how I did.

This is so confusing. Should I use "like" or "unlike"?

Comment: I included (what I think is) the question at the end of the post and I changed the formatting a little bit. You can find more tips in the [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners).

Comment: I would split it into two sentences. "I did that mean thing to her. Don't do that."

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the sentence is that it's slightly ambiguous no matter which word you use. (But the *how* makes it ungrammatical, so I will remove it in the following discussion.)

---

With *like*:

> Don't do that mean thing to her like I did.

This *could* be interpreted as saying:

> If you do that mean thing to her, don't do it in the *same manner* as I did.

---

With *unlike*:

> Don't do that mean thing to her unlike I did.

While this is awkward and should probably be rephrased, you could interpret it as:

> If you do that mean thing to her, don't do it *differently* than I did.

---

Neither sentence is necessarily telling the other person to *refrain* from doing that mean thing to her.

Following are two different ways of explicitly saying *not* to do the mean thing:

> Unlike me, don't do that mean thing to her.

Here, *unlike me* is used as qualifying (and nonessential) information. The essential information is what follows the comma. (*Don't do that mean thing to her.*)

> Don't be like me and do that mean thing to her.

Here, everything is essential. It's saying *don't be like me* and *don't do that mean thing to her*.

---

The use of *like* or *unlike* depends on how the rest of the sentence is constructed.

Comment: I kind of wanted that specific format because I was writing something.
A very clear explanation. Thank you!